# Label height according to text

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set label height according to text. currently it is showing only one line text. I have set constraint leading training and top but its not working.

Comment: Is it inside uitableview

Comment: where's your code?   "it's showing only one line" vs. what are you expecting/wanting it to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set no of lines to 0

```
  lbl.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: I accepted because this answer came very fast... Thnx

Comment: Welcome @ Mohammad Ishtiyak

Answer (score 2):

After providing proper constraint, `set no of lines 0 in storyboard` as given below in image-

[image]

And Set Constraints leading , training , top and bottom .

Answer (score 0):

set label.numberOfLines = 0

**If inside UITableView**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple lines of text based on content we can simply done via interface builder

1)set Lines to 0

2)Line break to wordwarp

For reference see below screenshot

[image]

Hope this will help you